# js rewrite previous elements in loop

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to push elements to array in loop but when my method returns a value, it always rewrites every element of array(probably returned value refers to the same object). I'm stuck with this problem for one day and I can't understand where is the problem because I've always tried to create new objects and assign them to 'var' not to 'let' variables. Here is my code:

```
setSeason(competitions, unions) {
    var categories = this.sortCategories(competitions);
    var unionsByCategories = new Array();
    let k = 0;
    for (; k < categories.length; k++) {
        unionsByCategories[k] = this.assignCompetitionsToUnions(unions[0], categories[k]);
    }
    this.setState({categories: unionsByCategories, refreshing: false})
}
```

and

```
assignCompetitionsToUnions(unions1, competitions) {
        var unions2 = this.alignUnions(unions1);
        let tempUnions = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < unions2.length; i++) {
            var tempUnionsCompetitions = new Array();
            var tempSubsCompetitions = new Array();
            if (Globals.checkNested(unions2[i], 'union')) {
                tempUnionsCompetitions = unions2[i].union;
                tempUnionsCompetitions['competitions'] = this.getCompetitionsById(unions2[i].union.id, competitions);
            }
            if (Globals.checkNested(unions2[i], 'subs')) {
                for (var j = 0; j < unions2[i].subs.length; j++) {
                    if (Globals.checkNested(unions2[i].subs[j], 'union')) {
                        tempSubsCompetitions[tempSubsCompetitions.length] = {union: unions2[i].subs[j].union};
                        tempSubsCompetitions[tempSubsCompetitions.length - 1]['union']['competitions'] =
                            this.getCompetitionsById(unions2[i].subs[j].union.id, competitions)
                    }
                }
            }
            tempUnions.push({union: tempUnionsCompetitions, subs: tempSubsCompetitions});
        }
        return tempUnions;
    }
```

Many thanks for any help.

`Answer updated by` @Knipe request

```
alignUnions(unions3) {
    let newUnions = unions3.subs;
    newUnions = [{union: unions3.union}].concat(newUnions);
    return newUnions.slice(0, newUnions.length - 1);
}

getCompetitionsById(id, competitions) {
    let tempCompetitions = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < competitions.length; i++) {
        if (competitions[i].union.id === id) {
            tempCompetitions.push(competitions[i]);
        }
    }
    return tempCompetitions;
}

sortCategories(competitions) {
    if (competitions.length === 0) return [];
    let categories = [];
    categories.push(competitions.filter((item) => {
        return item.category === 'ADULTS' && item.sex === 'M'
    }));
    categories.push(competitions.filter((item) => {
        return item.category === 'ADULTS' && item.sex === 'F'
    }));
    categories.push(competitions.filter((item) => {
        return item.category !== 'ADULTS'
    }));
    return categories;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it always rewrites every element of array(probably returned value
>   refers to the same object).

You are probably unintended mutating the content of the source array. I would recommend creating a copy of the array.

This is example of array mutation.

```
let array1 = [1,2,3];
let array2 = array1;
array2[0] = 4; // oops, now the content of array1 is [4,2,3]
```

To avoid mutating the source array you can create a copy of it

```
let array1 = [1,2,3];
let array2 = array1.slice();
array2[0] = 4; // the content of array1 is still the same [1,2,3]
```

> I've always tried to create new objects and assign them to 'var' not
>   to 'let' variables.

Using let/var will not prevent from rewrites. Creating new object with `new Array()` will not prevent rewrites.

It's hard to read where the bug is exactly from your code and description but you could try to avoid passing an array by reference and instead create a copy and pass the copy in function calls.

`this.assignCompetitionsToUnions(unions[0].slice(), categories[k])`

This is a shallow copy example, you might need to apply deep copy to make it work for your case.

Comment: This is only a shallow copy, which might not be enough. For a deep copy you could use a self-calling function, or else simply `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myThing))` if it consists entirely of plain objects and arrays and primitives. But personally I prefer to have conventions about which objects are considered mutable.

Comment: This answer is a little too theoretical for my liking. It doesn't say what to do in this particular situation. Perhaps Kunukn (like me) doesn't know where the problem is because the code calls other functions which we can't see the definitions of.

Comment: Thanks a lot both of you I tried to make a deep copy of `this.assignCompetitionsToUnions(unions[0], categories[k])` result, like this: 
`JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.assignCompetitionsToUnions(unions[0], categories[k])));` and now the elements are fine, so I assume that I was still referring to the same object? But I still doesn't know how to fix it without  making a copy of a result. I will update my answer with other methods which I'm using.